# Cannot install compass-sass grails plugin

Tags: grails

I have `grails 1.3.7` and am doing: `grails install-plugin compass-sass`

However, I get an error:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Dependencies resolved in 1202ms.
Running script /Users/shamoon/.sdkman/candidates/grails/current/scripts/InstallPlugin.groovy
Environment set to development
Resolving plugin compass-sass. Please wait...

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: org.grails.plugins#compass-sass;latest.integration

    ==== grailsPlugins: tried

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#compass-sass;latest.integration!compass-sass.zip:

      /Users/shamoon/GoogleDrive/Sites/IQ4/IQ4/IQ4Server/lib/compass-sass-[revision].zip

      /Users/shamoon/.grails/1.3.7/projects/IQ4Server/plugins/asynchronous-mail-0.2.1-SNAPSHOT/lib/compass-sass-[revision].zip

      /Users/shamoon/.grails/1.3.7/projects/IQ4Server/plugins/burning-image-0.5.0/lib/compass-sass-[revision].zip

      /Users/shamoon/.grails/1.3.7/projects/IQ4Server/plugins/cache-headers-1.1.5/lib/compass-sass-[revision].zip

      /Users/shamoon/.grails/1.3.7/projects/IQ4Server/plugins/cached-resources-1.0/lib/compass-sass-[revision].zip

      /Users/shamoon/.grails/1.3.7/projects/IQ4Server/plugins/database-migration-0.2.1/lib/compass-sass-[revision].zip

      /Users/shamoon/.grails/1.3.7/projects/IQ4Server/plugins/hibernate-1.3.7/lib/compass-sass-[revision].zip

      /Users/shamoon/.grails/1.3.7/projects/IQ4Server/plugins/jamon-0.1/lib/compass-sass-[revision].zip

      /Users/shamoon/.grails/1.3.7/projects/IQ4Server/plugins/jaxrs-0.5/lib/compass-sass-[revision].zip

      /Users/shamoon/.grails/1.3.7/projects/IQ4Server/plugins/mail-1.0/lib/compass-sass-[revision].zip

      /Users/shamoon/.grails/1.3.7/projects/IQ4Server/plugins/oauth-0.10/lib/compass-sass-[revision].zip

      /Users/shamoon/.grails/1.3.7/projects/IQ4Server/plugins/quartz-0.4.2/lib/compass-sass-[revision].zip

      /Users/shamoon/.grails/1.3.7/projects/IQ4Server/plugins/resources-1.1.6/lib/compass-sass-[revision].zip

      /Users/shamoon/.grails/1.3.7/projects/IQ4Server/plugins/sanitizer-0.6.2/lib/compass-sass-[revision].zip

      /Users/shamoon/.grails/1.3.7/projects/IQ4Server/plugins/solr-0.3c/lib/compass-sass-[revision].zip

      /Users/shamoon/.grails/1.3.7/projects/IQ4Server/plugins/spring-security-core-1.2.6/lib/compass-sass-[revision].zip

      /Users/shamoon/.grails/1.3.7/projects/IQ4Server/plugins/taggable-1.0.1/lib/compass-sass-[revision].zip

      /Users/shamoon/.grails/1.3.7/projects/IQ4Server/plugins/tomcat-1.3.7/lib/compass-sass-[revision].zip

      /Users/shamoon/.grails/1.3.7/projects/IQ4Server/plugins/webxml-1.4.1/lib/compass-sass-[revision].zip

      /Users/shamoon/.grails/1.3.7/projects/IQ4Server/plugins/zipped-resources-1.0/lib/compass-sass-[revision].zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      /Users/shamoon/.sdkman/candidates/grails/current/lib/compass-sass-[revision].xml

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#compass-sass;latest.integration!compass-sass.zip:

      /Users/shamoon/.sdkman/candidates/grails/current/lib/compass-sass-[revision].zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      /Users/shamoon/.sdkman/candidates/grails/current/dist/compass-sass-[revision].xml

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#compass-sass;latest.integration!compass-sass.zip:

      /Users/shamoon/.sdkman/candidates/grails/current/dist/compass-sass-[revision].zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#compass-sass;latest.integration!compass-sass.zip:

      /Users/shamoon/.sdkman/candidates/grails/current/plugins/grails-compass-sass-[revision].zip

    ==== grailsCentral: tried

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#compass-sass;latest.integration!compass-sass.zip:

      http://svn.codehaus.org/grails-plugins/grails-compass-sass/tags/LATEST_RELEASE/grails-compass-sass-[revision].zip

    ==== grailsCore: tried

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#compass-sass;latest.integration!compass-sass.zip:

      http://svn.codehaus.org/grails/trunk/grails-plugins/grails-compass-sass/tags/LATEST_RELEASE/grails-compass-sass-[revision].zip

    ==== mavenCentral: tried

      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/compass-sass/[revision]/compass-sass-[revision].pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#compass-sass;latest.integration!compass-sass.zip:

      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/compass-sass/[revision]/compass-sass-[revision].zip

    ==== http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/maven: tried

      http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/maven/org/grails/plugins/compass-sass/[revision]/compass-sass-[revision].pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#compass-sass;latest.integration!compass-sass.zip:

      http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/maven/org/grails/plugins/compass-sass/[revision]/compass-sass-[revision].zip

    ==== http://download.java.net/maven/2/: tried

      http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/grails/plugins/compass-sass/[revision]/compass-sass-[revision].pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#compass-sass;latest.integration!compass-sass.zip:

      http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/grails/plugins/compass-sass/[revision]/compass-sass-[revision].zip

    ==== localMavenResolver: tried

      /Users/shamoon/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/compass-sass/[revision]/compass-sass-[revision].pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#compass-sass;latest.integration!compass-sass.zip:

      /Users/shamoon/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/compass-sass/[revision]/compass-sass-[revision].zip

    ==== https://repository.sonatype.org/content/repositories/central: tried

      https://repository.sonatype.org/content/repositories/central/org/grails/plugins/compass-sass/[revision]/compass-sass-[revision].pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#compass-sass;latest.integration!compass-sass.zip:

      https://repository.sonatype.org/content/repositories/central/org/grails/plugins/compass-sass/[revision]/compass-sass-[revision].zip

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: org.grails.plugins#compass-sass;latest.integration: not found

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


Error resolving plugin [name:compass-sass, group:org.grails.plugins, version:latest.integration].
Plugin not found for name [compass-sass] and version [not specified]
```

I want to install 0.7 as indicated here: https://grails.org/plugin/compass-sass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay - apparently the repo for plugins is different for `1.3.7`.
 I needed to add `mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo/"` to my `grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy` file